# How to put css selectors into php generated html code

Tags: php, string, quotes, double-quotes

I'm trying to make one little prototype on PHP and Wordpress, and I can't find out what is wrong with this.

### This code is fine:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect( "localhost", "root");
    mysql_select_db( "wp");
                  
    $result = mysql_query("select score from test"); 
    $argument = mysql_query("select level from test");
    echo "<table>\n";
    echo "<tfoot><tr>\n";
    while ($myarg = mysql_fetch_row($argument))
    {
    printf("<th>%s</th>\n", $myarg[0]);
    }
    echo "</tr></tfoot>\n";
    echo "<tbody><tr>\n";
    while ($myres = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
    printf("<td>%s</td>\n", $myres[0]);
    }
    echo "</tr></tbody>\n";
    echo "</table>\n";  
?>
```

But when I add selector to table, like this:

```
echo "<table id="data">\n";
```

I've got the following error on the page:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in ... ...

Same thing when I add styles.

Comment: Your title is totally misleading...? "How to put css selectors into php generated html code" should be something like "unexpected T_STRING" or "Error including id into table in a string" etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The problem

The problem is that you try to print a character that has a meaning in the PHP language. You try to print a double quote but in this case it means end of the string (that you started with the first double quote) for the praser.

### Solution

Use single quotes for echo:

```
echo '<table id="data">\n';
```

Escape the special character you want to print:

```
echo "<table id=\"data\">\n";
```

### Explanation

You got a prase error because when the praser arrives at the end of `echo "<table id="` part, it expects a `;` as a close for your command or a comma [with other parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). That is the reason why it says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, **expecting ',' or ';'**

Also it says he got a `T_STRING` (instead of the expected values explained previously) that is the `data` you typed.
Furthermore the error message says that he is a syntax error. So it has a problem with what you typed, you used the wrong syntax.

### Conclusion

Analyse your error messages, the praser gives them to help you to solve your problem. Also copying the error message to an online search engine can solve you a problem incredibly fast.

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes instead like this

```
echo "<table id='data'>\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try, use single quotes

```
echo "<table id='data'>\n";
```